# TypeORM insert with relationId

Tags: javascript, orm, typeorm

I use TypeORM, and simply I want to insert a row by using `relationId`. But it's not working as I expected.

Here is my entity:

```
@Entity()
export default class Address extends BaseEntity {

    @Column({
        type: 'varchar',
        length: 255,
    })
    public title: number;

    @Column({
        type: 'varchar',
        length: 2000,
    })
    public value: number;

    @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'userId' })
    public user: User;

    @RelationId((address: Address) => address.user)
    public userId: number;

}
```

When I try to add like the below example, it adds `null` `userId` which I do not expect

```
{
    "title": "My home address",
    "value": "Lorep Ipsum Sit Amet",
    "userId": 4
}
```

[image: column screenshot]

When I change the payload, everything works perfectly.

```
{
    "title": "Ev adresim",
    "value": "Nova Suites",
    "user": 4
}
```

I do not want to use a payload like the above. I addicted to define a descriptive variable naming. Thanks for all contribution and all answer from now.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It looks like this is a TypeORM issue with the @RelationId decorator: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3867.

Instead of using @RelationId you can decorate the userId with @Column, when the name of the JoinColumn is equal to the number column name, TypeORM matches both and you can either set the userId or the user and TypeORM will handle it:

```
@ManyToOne(type => User, user => user)
@JoinColumn({ name: 'userId' })
public user: User;

@Column()
public userId: number;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate. Actually, I had tried this solution but It didn't worked. It gaves me an error which is `error: Error: UNKNOWN_CODE_PLEASE_REPORT: Referencing column 'userId' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'FK_d25f1ea79e282cc8a42bd616aa3' are incompatible.`

I have dropped the table as well, but it doesnt work as I expected. That means it doesnt add foreignkey automatically

Comment: I checked the error that the terminal was saying. I realized that when we define the properties of userId column the same with the referenced table's Id. It works fine. Could you update your answer according to this. When you update the answer, I am going to mark your answer. Thereby, people who faced same issue able to find their problem as well. It should be like this -->

    `@Column({
        type: 'integer',
        unsigned: true,
    })
    public userId: number;`

due to the fact that in my base entity class, I defined primary id's as a unsigned

Comment: Ok, glad I could helped. I updated the answer, but I'm not 100% sure what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

The `@RelationId` decorator works in one direction.
As written in the [documentation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/decorator-reference.md):

> Loads id (or ids) of specific relations into properties.
>
> Relation id is used only for representation. The underlying relation is not added/removed/changed when chaining the value.

As suggested, You can use the `@Column` decorator to to update the value.

Comment: You're totally right. Actually, The answer is given by @JudgeFudge is almost correct. I have commented on some parts. When he/she changed her/his answer, I am going to approve that answer.

Comment: @HalilİbrahimÖzdoğan Your question changed? The answer I gave wasn't relevant?  how did you solve the issue?

Comment: no mate your answer is relevant as well. That's why I have upvoted your answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

As Noam has pointed out, you cannot use the `@RelationId()` decorated property to assign a relation. Instead you should use the relation itself.

If you have an instance of the object like `user` below, you can pass it straight away. For the offer I had only ID, I've been able to work around this limitation though by creating an object with just an `id` property. Now I don't have to retrieve the whole object from the DB which would be waste of resources.

```js
subscriptionRepository
    .insert({
        offer: {id: offerId},
        user: user,
    })
```

For your reference, this is an excerpt of my entity definition.

```js
@Entity()
export class Subscription {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @ManyToOne(
        () => Offer,
        (offer: Offer) => offer.subscriptions
    )
    offer: Offer;

    @ManyToOne(
        () => User,
        (user: User) => user.subscriptions
    )
    user: User;
}
```