# ManyToOne field doesn't appear in Parent resolver

Tags: graphql, nestjs, typeorm, resolver

I'm having some trouble with an entity in a NestJS project. I'm using TypeOrm to manage the PostgreSQL database, GraphQL and DataLoader to load, for example, the users in the database.

Now, I've this entity:

```js
import { ObjectType, Field, ID } from "@nestjs/graphql";
import { Column, Entity, JoinColumn, ManyToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
import { Comment } from "./comment.entity";
import { User } from "./user.entity";

@ObjectType()
@Entity({name: 'comments_likes'})
export class CommentLike {

    @Field()
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Field()
    @Column({type: 'timestamptz', nullable: false})
    liked_at: Date

    @Field()
    @ManyToOne(() => Comment, (comment) => comment.id)
    @JoinColumn({name: 'refId'})
    ref: number;

    @Field({nullable: false})
    @ManyToOne(() => User, (user)  => user.id)
    @JoinColumn({name: 'ownerId'})
    owner: number
}
```

As you can see, I have four different columns: the `id`, the `liked_at` timestamp, the `ref` to the comment id, and the `owner` that is a number that represents a user in users table.

Now, this is my resolver:

```js
import { Args, Context, Mutation, Parent, Query, ResolveField, Resolver }    from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { User } from '../../models/user.entity';
import { CommentLike } from '../../models/like_comment.entity';
import { LikeCommentInput } from './input/like-comment.input';
import { LikesCommentService } from './likes-comment.service';
import DataLoader from 'dataloader';

@Resolver(CommentLike)
export class LikesCommentResolver {

    constructor(
        private readonly likesCommentService: LikesCommentService
    ) {}

    @Query(() => CommentLike)
    public async getCommentLikeById(@Args('id') id: number) : Promise<CommentLike> {
        return this.likesCommentService.commentLikeRepo.findOne({id: id});
    }

    @Mutation(() => CommentLike)
    public async addCommentLike(@Args('data') input: LikeCommentInput) : Promise<CommentLike> {
        const newLike = new CommentLike;
        newLike.liked_at = input.liked_at;
        newLike.owner = input.owner
        newLike.ref = input.comment;

        return this.likesCommentService.commentLikeRepo.save(newLike);
    }

    @ResolveField('owner', () => User)
    public async getOwner(@Parent() commentLike: CommentLike, @Context('usersLoader') usersLoader: DataLoader<number, User>) : Promise<User> {
        console.log(commentLike, typeof commentLike);
        return usersLoader.load(commentLike.owner);
    }

}
```

My problem is in the `getCommentLikeById`, when I try to run this GraphQL query:

```
query {
    getCommentLikeById(id: 2) {
        owner {
            username
        }
    }
}
```

As error, I got `The loader.load() function must be called with a value,but got: undefined.` that is referred to the `ResolveProperty` function `getOwner`. In this funciton I added a `console.log` just to see the `@Parent` parameter, and I saw that I receive only the `id` and the `liked_at` timestamp and not the `owner` field either the `ref` field.

I tried to add `{eager: true}` to the `ManyToOne`, but in this way I receive back all the `User` object, and I want only the `id` in order to load the User through the `DataLoader`.

Thank you for any advice on how to do this :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it editing the entity in this way

```js
import { ObjectType, Field, ID } from "@nestjs/graphql";
import { Column, Entity, JoinColumn, ManyToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, RelationId } from "typeorm";
import { Comment } from "./comment.entity";
import { User } from "./user.entity";

@ObjectType()
@Entity({name: 'comments_likes'})
export class CommentLike {

    @Field()
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Field()
    @Column({type: 'timestamptz', nullable: false})
    liked_at: Date

    @Field()
    @ManyToOne(() => Comment, (comment) => comment.id)
    @JoinColumn({name: 'refId'})
    ref: number;

    @Field({nullable: false})
    @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.id)
    @JoinColumn({name: 'ownerId'})
    owner: User

    @Column()
    ownerId: number
}
```

Just added at the end one `Column`, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61361008/typeorm-insert-with-relationid).

Maybe this will help someone having the same problem!